# How to delay response until POST payload is validated

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

How do I delay returning the response until I have read the payload and confirmed it is a good request?

In the following code, the method is returning before the `data` event is fired, thus it is always `200`.

```
http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    var payloadValid = true;        // <-- Initialise an 'payloadValid' variable to true

    request.on('data', function(chunk) {
        payloadValid = false;       // <-- set it to true when the payload is examined
    });

/*
 * This is executed before the payload is validated
 */

    response.writeHead(payloadValid ? 200 : 400, {    // <-- return 200 or 400, depending on the payloadValid  variable
        'Content-Length': 4,
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
    });
    response.write('Yup!');
    response.end();
})
.listen(PORT_NUMBER);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just put the response method into the function callback. Code below. Works in postman.

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    var payloadValid = true;     

    request.on('data', function(chunk) {
        payloadValid = false;
        response.writeHead(payloadValid ? 200 : 400, {   
            'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
        });
        response.write('Yup!');
        response.end();     
    });
})
.listen(8080);
```

Comment: It should be noted that the code above will return `Yup!` for both status code responses.

Comment: I hope this is just a proof of concept and not an actual production code :)

Comment: I wouldn't put it into production, no :)